# Android Proximity Alert not fire

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, proximity

I try to set up Proximity alert below is my code but Its not firing

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.mycomputer.xxx.Util.ProximityIntentReceiver");
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.example.mycomputer.xxx.Util.ProximityIntentReceiver");
PendingIntent proximityIntent;
requestcodex=1;

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), requestcodex , intent, 0);
    locationManager.addProximityAlert(Database.LatLngTest[i][1], Database.LatLngTest[i][2], Rd, -1, proximityIntent);
    requestcodex++;
    getContext().registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);
}
```

I am sending Mock location to test on real device mock location follows correct path but broadcast listener is not called

ProximityIntentReceiver

```
public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000 ;
int id = NOTIFICATION_ID;
boolean noti = false;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
    Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);
    String msg;
    if (entering) {
        msg = "Entering ";
        noti = true;

    } else {
        msg = "Exiting ";
        noti = true;
    }

    final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,requestcodex, notificationIntent, 0);
    final Notification notification = createNotification();


    notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);


    if (id == NOTIFICATION_ID) {
            //Build Dialog

    }
}



private Notification createNotification() {
    // Notification       
    return notification;
   }
}
```

Thank !!!